# Wp7 Storyboard Animation Setting Appearing Horizon

Tags: wpf, silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml

I'm just wondering if there is a way to set a vertical threshold of where you want a story board item to appear on the screen (when sliding in and out) so that it doesn't have to slide across everything on the screen when it's popping in and out. I have an list of items that get flipped though according to a timer event but when an item comes onto the screen it passes over all the other buttons and user controls and it doesn't look very pretty.  It would be nice if I could just make it appear as if the item was sliding right out of the background into position.

I have two storyboard animations, one to deal with the object sliding in the other to deal with the current object that needs to be slid out. There are also arrow buttons on either side of the content area and currently the objects are sliding over the arrows, which is what I am trying to eliminate. Here is the storyboard code:

```
    <Storyboard x:Key="newsIn" x:Name="newsIn">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateX)" Storyboard.TargetName="newsContent">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="500"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="0">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                    <BounceEase EasingMode="EaseIn" Bounces="0"/>
                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>

    <Storyboard x:Key="newsOut" x:Name="newsOut">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateX)" Storyboard.TargetName="newsContent">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="-500">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                    <BounceEase EasingMode="EaseIn" Bounces="0"/>
                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
```

I don't know if I described this very clearly but if someone has done this before or knows of a resource where I could learn to do this your help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks for your time.

**ANSWER:** Put the elements your animating inside a canvas (or some container) and use the Clip property to only desplay them when they apear inside the dedicated area like so.

```
    <Canvas Name="newsContent" Grid.Column="1" >
       <Canvas.Clip>
           <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,372,200"/>
       </Canvas.Clip>
       <Ui element/>
       <Ui element2/>
       ....
    </Canvas>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, can you try using clipToBounds = true on the control that is your content container i.e the control that contains the "news" items (i.e. canvas or grid etc).  Make sure your arrows etc are not in the same container

Comment: O my god, the Clip property is exactly what I was looking for! I can't believe I didn't find that earlier. I just made a Canvans with a clip property around its edges and then had my UI elements slide in and out of that.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able just animate the opacity property?  Make it so that it only becomes visible after it is in position

Comment: But then you wouldn't get the sliding effect, I'm looking for my grid to slide into view but not starting at the end of the screen. So you would first see a tiny part of the grid then more and more as it slides into view. Just like when tap an hold to pin something to the start menu on WP7, you see that menu slide down from nowhere. Any Ideas?

Comment: Unless you were talking about animating the opacity on part of the grid and slowly increase the amount that you can see as it's sliding into position. Is that possible?

Comment: Its hard to comment without being able to see your animation code.  But yes, opacity on the grid.  It does not need to be gradual though you can just time it so that it becomes visible once it passes your "threshold"

Comment: There is no way make the object slide in from behind everything else? That would be ideal, then you would only see it when it entered the transparent region, that is the look I was going for (so it would be sliding out from behind the arrow that's controlling the list switching instead of sliding over it from the side of the screen).

Comment: There would almost definately be a way, but without you posting the animation etc I can't visualise what you are trying to do.

Comment: Ok I updated the question, if there is a way to make it look like it's sliding in and out from behind the arrow buttons on either side insdead of coming from the side of the screen that would be great (I still haven't found anything). Thanks!