# WP7 Animation through Storyboard

Tags: windows-phone-7, storyboard

I have gone through the fadein/fadeout tutorial that is on [this](http://windowsphonegeek.com/articles/WP7-Animations-in-depthndash-Overview-and-Getting-Started) page:

For the next increment, I wish to have images simply moving horizontally. So for example, If I get 10 images and line them up, how can I make them move off the screen slowly.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My question here might help: [Wp7 Storyboard Animation Setting Appearing Horizon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11092134/wp7-storyboard-animation-setting-appearing-horizon)

The storyboard code I was using moves images horizontally across the screen with an easing function (you can take that part out if you want). You can use it if you put it into

```
    <phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
         ......
    </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

Then you can call it from the code-behind like so:

```
    Storyboard myAnimation = this.Resources["newsIn"] as Storyboard;
    myAnimation.Completed += delegate
        {
           //Do something
        }
    Storyboard.SetTarget(myAnimation, this.ObjectToMove);
    myAnimation.Begin();
```

Hope that helps, let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: Hi there. Thank you for the response. Do you know of any online tutorial though as they're really easy to digest and learn from. As oppose to answers from questions. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: I would suggest using blend to get the basics of the story board you want to create and then go into the XAML and edit it manually to fine tune it how you want. Here is a decent walk-through of how to create storyboards in blend -> http://www.silverlightbuzz.com/2009/10/12/animating-with-storyboards-in-blend/  or if your looking for a video tutorial check this out -> http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=flIbZ_1dJZ0

Comment: Wow. awesome, thank you. I'll keep in touch if that's okay. Your advice is extremely helpful.